# RDS Parameter groups - dynamic and static

Tags: amazon-rds

What's an example of a dynamic parameter vs a static parameter as mentioned here?

> Here are some important points you should know about working with parameters in a DB parameter group:
>
> When you change a dynamic parameter and save the DB parameter group, the change is applied immediately regardless of the Apply Immediately setting. When you change a static parameter and save the DB parameter group, the parameter change will take effect after you manually reboot the DB instance.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html

Answer (score 5):

Open up and look at a parameter group in the console, or use `aws rds describe-db-parameters`, as documented on link you provided.

Each parameter is labeled as being static or dynamic, in both of these places.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Michael - sqlbot said (I can't comment, tried to edit but was justifiably rejected)

This label represents -

> ApplyType -> (string)
>
> Specifies the engine specific parameters type.

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-parameters.html#output:~:text=value.-,ApplyType](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-parameters.html#output:%7E:text=value.-,ApplyType)

Comment: You could add that to Michael's answer by editing it.

Comment: @jasie I tried to edit but I was rejected, I can't add a comment yet either.